# Running ogr2ogr in Python on Windows

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I run ogr2ogr to transfer geometrical data from a pgsql (PostGIS) database to a MS SQL one. It works quite well. I'm trying to achieve exactly the same result in Python, as I'm planning to use programming to automate the entire process and add some error reporting to it, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I run Python 3 in an Anaconda environment in which I installed GDAL.

How do I run the following code in native Python/GDAL?

```
ogr2ogr -lco PRECISION=NO -lco SRID=27700 -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=NO -lco OVERWRITE=YES -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt
-f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=server;database=db;trusted_connection=yes" 
PG:"dbname=db host=host port=1234 user=user password=pass"
"schema.table" -t_srs "EPSG:27700" -s_srs "EPSG:27700" -a_srs "EPSG:27700" -gt 100000 -progress -nln schema.table
```

I can load the GDAL library in Python and there is an OGR component, but I can't find any ogr2ogr component.

Comment: Check this https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.GDALVectorTranslateOptions-class.html. BTW it makes never sense to have both -t_srs and -a_srs and now you are using also -lco SRID=27700.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [gdal](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) package for Python. However, the syntax of the functions is very close to the C++ API and therefore rather difficult. For raster data there is the wrapper [rasterio](https://pypi.org/project/rasterio/). For vector data there is the wrapper [fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/). The [documentation](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#rules-of-thumb) describes for which cases `fiona` is suitable.

You can also access `ogr2ogr` from the command line inside Python. To simplify this, you can use the script `ogr2ogr.py` ([link](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py)). This is called as follows:

```py
import ogr2ogr

ogr2ogr.main([
  'ogr2ogr',
  '-f', 'GPKG', 'output.gpkg' ,
  'input.gpkg'
])
```

(taken from this [blog post](https://jakobmiksch.eu/post/gdal_ogr/#python))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subprocess to run any system commands (i.e. if you didn't want to install the gdal python module and use cmd gdal commands).

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(r'ogr2ogr -lco PRECISION=NO -lco SRID=27700 -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=NO -lco OVERWRITE=YES -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=server;database=db;trusted_connection=yes" PG:"dbname=db host=host port=1234 user=user password=pass" "schema.table" -t_srs "EPSG:27700" -s_srs "EPSG:27700" -a_srs "EPSG:27700" -gt 100000 -progress -nln schema.table', check=True, shell=True)
```

another example using pgsql2shp:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(r'pgsql2shp -f "output_shapefile.shp" -h host -u postgres_user -P postgres_password database_name schema.export_table', check=True, shell=True)
```